# Testing whether limit exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I have the following function:

$$f:\mathbb{R^{2}}\to \mathbb{R},\;\;f(x,y):=\frac{x-y}{x^{2}+y^{2}},\;\;(x,y)\neq (0,0).$$

I would like to test whether its limit exists at $(0,0)$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{x-y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x}{x^{2}}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} = +\infty$$

$$\lim_{y
\to 0}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right) = -\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\frac{y}{y^{2}}\right) = -\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{y} = -\infty$$

The divergent nature of the two limits indicates that the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$$

does not exist.

It would have been sufficient to show that at least one of the first two limits diverge.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @curiousMind_85 no

Comment: Here is a link that also might help you . Please read it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit

Comment: Your reasoning seems to be perfectly fine to me, see my comment on Gandalf's answer.

Comment: Can we also make the following transfromation in order to approach the answer? $x = rcos(\phi),\;\;y = rsin(\phi)$ and then obtain $f(r,\phi) = \frac{cos(\phi)-sin(\phi)}{r}$

Comment: Yes you can freely use polar coordinates and show that it does not exist.

Comment: @curiousMind_85 That transformation is often helpful, but we need to deal with it carefully in general. If you take the limit $\lim_{r \to 0^+} f(r,\phi)$ treating $\phi$ as constant, then we see that we get different answers depending on $\phi$, so the limit here does not exist. But this only tells us the limit along *straight-line* paths to $(0,0)$; there are (very rare in practice) examples where all such limits are the same, but the limit at $(0,0)$ still does not exist.

Comment: We can also utilize the sequence $a_n:=\left(\frac{p}{n},\frac{q}{n}\right)$ well, where $p$ and $q$ are arbitrary integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all limit not existing finitely and limit not existing are two separate things.

Double limit or usual Limit of a multivariale function is $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}$ and it is not the same as iterated limit $\lim_{x\to 0}(\lim_{y\to 0})$ . Please read [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit)

In this case the limit itself does not exist. The way you have shown is not complete as you have shown that the ITERATED limits do not exist. However the existence of iterated limits is neither a necessary nor a sufficient condition for the double limit or simply the limit of a multivariable function to exist.

example:- $x\sin(\frac{1}{y})$ . Here the double limit exists but one of the iterated limit does not.

Following the wiki : - $\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ has it's iterated limits equal to $0$ but the double limit does not exist. It is because if we take approach through the path $y=mx$ we get $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{mx^{2}}{(1+m^{2})x^{2}}=\frac{m}{1+m^{2}}$ which is different for different values of $m$. But limit if it exists MUST be unique. Hence it does not exist.

So what you need to do is the following:-

You can prove that if the double limit of a multivariable function $F(x,y)$ exists then for any continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{y\to 0}g(y)=0$ , you will have

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} F(f(x),g(y))$$ must exist.

So here you take $f(x)=0$ and $g(y)=y$ to show that you get $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ which does not exists. (It is not $\infty$ as you said in your question as the left hand limit and right hand limit tend to positive and negative infinities). And here this suffices to say that the Double limit does not exist. But you can go a step further and show for $g(y)=0$ and $f(x)=x$ too.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I believe that this answer is not correct. Here is my reasoning: If $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ existed, then this would in particular mean that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,0)$ exists. The OP has shown that this is not the case. $x\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$ is not a counterexample since it isn't even defined in ${y=0}$.

Comment: @msgcas . Please check before commenting . a function need not be defined at a point to discuss about limit. $(0,0)$ is a accumulation point of the domain and hence you can talk about the limit. It is trivial to see that $|x\sin(\frac{1}{y})|\leq |x|$ and hence the limit is $0$. The op has shown that the iterated limits does not exist. Which is not the same as $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,0)$ does not exist. Ofcourse it boils down to the same but taking limit and setting a path as a constant $0$ are two different things.

Comment: Right, I can see your reasoning. Still, the argument of the op works perfectly fine, since he considers a continuous function defined on $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{0\}$, for which $x\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)$ is not a counterexample.

Comment: @msgcas Where is the continuous function? Is limit $\lim_{x\to 0} f(a,x)= f(a,0)$ true if $f$ is not continuous ? . So here how can you conclude that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,y)= f(0,y)$ uniformly as a function of $y$ ? . You will only end up misleading the op by these comments. Please refer to any real analysis texts like Apostol or Rudin and verify your claims before commenting .

Comment: I think it's fair to say the reasoning in the question is *equivalent* to valid reasoning, but not actually the same thing. To show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ does not exist, it is sufficient (though not necessary) to argue that the limits that approach $(0,0)$ along the positive $y$-axis and along the positive $x$-axis are different. This immediately gives us $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x-0}{x^2+0^2}$ and $\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{0-y}{0^2+y^2}$; taking a double limit is not part of the definition, but is harmless *in this case* since $\frac{x-y}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous away from $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I didn't say anything about uniform convergence. All I'm saying is the following: If $f:\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with the property that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ does exist, then the iterated limits must exist, too, and equal the limit. As this is the situation the op is in, it means that the op's reasoning is correct.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I can support that. I believe, we're not too far apart in what we're saying.

Comment: @msgcas . Again I point out that the op is not considering a " continuius function".  He is directly applying the itereated limit and as a result he is getting the same result as he would if he used the constant "0" function in place of y or x.  But that is NOT the correct approach even though in this case it boils down to the same as I said in my previous comment. Also there are other mistakes the limit of 1/x is not infinity. It does not exist.

Comment: By not the correct approach I mean that taking iterated limits and showing that they don't exist neither prove nor disprove the existence of double limits. But replacing a limit with a constant continuous function like 0 is a completely different affair which yields the correct "REASONING" albeit both method might yield the same result.

Comment: I believe @MishaLavrov's comment sums it up in good way, this has really become an unreasonably long discussion for an easy problem. You're of course correct about the non-existence of the limit of $1/x$.